# Пакетная регистрация зависимостей в asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

> Внимание! Это краткий перевод вопроса [Implement dependency injection
>   outside of Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40306928/5752652)

Есть проект asp.net core со множеством репозиториев и сервисов, в файле Startup.cs огромная нечитаемая портянка регистрации:

```
services.AddTransient<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
services.AddTransient<ICityRepository, CityRepository>();
//..... and so on

services.AddTransient<ICityService, CityService>();
services.AddTransient<IContactServiceBase, ContactServiceBase>();
//..... and so on
```

Можно ли каким-то образом зарегистрировать все эти зависимости более коротким способом?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40306928/5752652

Answer (score 1):

Подобные вещи в англоязычной литературе называются [batch registration](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdependency-injection%5D+%5Bc%23%5D+batch+registration), иногда применяется ещё термин [assembly scanning](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html).

В asp.net core [есть возможность](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.0#default-service-container-replacement) заменить встроенный DI на autofac, который умеет сканировать сборки и регистрировать типы:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

А встроенный DI (до сих пор - даже в core 2.1) не поддерживает сканирование сборок :(

Однако вы можете воспользоваться [проектом Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor): установив его из nuget вы сможете регистрировать зависимости следующим образом:

```
var collection = new ServiceCollection();

collection.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<ITransientService>()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ITransientService>())
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .WithTransientLifetime()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IScopedService>())
            .As<IScopedService>()
            .WithScopedLifetime());
```

Если вы не хотите подключать дополнительные пакеты, то можете написать небольшой экстеншн:

```
public static void AddScopedFromAssembly(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
{
    var allServices = assembly.GetTypes().Where(p =>
        p.GetTypeInfo().IsClass &&
        !p.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract);
    foreach (var type in allServices)
    {
        var allInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
        var mainInterfaces = allInterfaces.Except
                (allInterfaces.SelectMany(t => t.GetInterfaces()));
        foreach (var itype in mainInterfaces)
        {
            services.AddScoped(itype, type); // if you want you can pass lifetime as a parameter
        }
    }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
 services.AddScopedFromAssembly(assembly);
```

Comment: очень удобная вещь. Единственное неудобство - понять в большом проекте что же за тип резолвится через интерфейс, если реализаций этого типа больше одного - приходится дебажить или логи ставить.